# Starting Nginx gives org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 error

Tags: ubuntu

I just started to build a ubuntu server on DigitalOcean. When I start the nginx service, it gives the following error:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ service nginx start
Failed to start nginx.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
```

I have never seen this before and searching on google seemed the solutions were not quite straightforward.

Comment: Make sure you have your configuration file. This one:       /etc/nginx/conf.d/MyCustomWebsite.conf

Answer (score 167, accepted):

stupid me, forgot to run `sudo`

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Comment: what a poorly handled error!  It should say something about permissions!

Comment: can anyone please explain what that error means?

Comment: @Neo, PolicyKit is (more or less) systemd's version of `sudo`.  If it's running, systemd can query it to see if the user has permission to perform a task such as starting nginx.  Basically what's happening here is that systemd tries to start nginx as-is, but that fails because the user doesn't have permission.  Systemd then tries to contact PolicyKit for permission, but since it isn't running, that fails and systemd complains about it, when it should be complaining about the lack of permission.